# AES encrypt not working in php

Tags: php

below code runs in PHP it will returns empty string. But same query run in mysql it shows some values.

```
<?php
   $encrypt_query = "select aes_encrypt('$string','$key') as encrypt_data";
   $encrypt_result = mysql_query($encrypt_query); 
   print_r($encrypt_result);// it returns resource id #7
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($encrypt_result);
   return $row['encrypt_data'];//it return empty
?>
```

Comment: Is there really no "FROM" in your query?

Comment: yes.just need to encrypt the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
   $encrypt_query = "select aes_encrypt('$string','$key') as encrypt_data";
   $encrypt_result = mysql_query($encrypt_query); 
   print_r($encrypt_result);// it returns resource id #7
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($encrypt_result)){
     echo  $row['encrypt_data'];
   }
?>
```

//Or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($encrypt_result);
echo $row[0];
```